# Is Rundeck job number accessible through an "option variable"?

Tags: rundeck

You know how, with a Rundeck job, when you define an launch command script, you can reference job run option variables with things like `@option_var_1@`.  Is there a symbol like this that evaluates to the number of the job run?  I'd like to pass that value to my executable as a command-line variable.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking for the execution id of the job.

`job.execid`: ID of the current Execution